# Firebase Phone Authentication requires additional configuration steps

Tags: firebase-authentication, firebase-console

Attempting setup of Firebase Phone authentication in Firebase console.

Message says

> Phone Authentication requires additional configuration steps. Follow
> the steps for your platform.

[image]

I am using the Web platform and the [steps are found here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/phone-auth?hl=en&authuser=1)
[image]

I am lost on this step:

> On the same page, if the domain that will host your app isn't listed
> in the OAuth redirect domains section, add your domain.

What does Firebase want me to do to complete the phone authentication setup?

EDIT: I have the 3 default authorized domains that Firebase created when it created my app.

Comment: Instead of saying "What am I missing?" It would be more clear if you explained specifically what you found confusing about the messaging in question.  We don't know what you're missing because we don't know what you found confusing, or what you tried that didn't work the way you expected.

Answer (score 2):

The **OAuth redirect domains** is somewhere under the *Authentication* portion of the Firebase Console.

By default `localhost`, `PROJECT_ID.web.app`, and `PROJECT_ID.firebaseapp.com` have already been added to this domain list.

If you will serve your wep app in any custom domains asides from those 3 (which you most probably would), add the custom domain(s) in the Authentication-specific settings.

The above is basically what your quoted line is saying:

> On the same page, if the domain that will host your app isn't listed in the OAuth redirect domains section, add your domain.

The following steps should get you there.

1. Visit this link: https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/authentication/settings, it will ask you to choose your Firebase project and then take you to the Authentication-specific settings of the project.

[image: authentication_page_console_screenshot]

2. Click on **Authorised domains** as on the screenshot.

[image: domains_settings_authentication]

3. Click on **Add domain**, then add your domain.

---

You are good to go.

The idea of whitelisting domains is that if there are any requests to Firebase Auth APIs with your project's details from domains not listed in these settings, Firebase will reject those requests.

It is simply something we all want to maximize security/control over our Firebase projects.

Comment: Thank you for response. I have the default 3 domains which Firebase created when I created my app. They are `localhost`, `myapp.firebase.app` and `myapp.web.app` but I am still getting the message to setup phone auth. Do I need a custom domain like mycustomdomain.com?

Comment: No you don't need a custom domain to setup phone auth. Where are you getting the message? If it is in the Firebase console, then you can ignore it. See it as just a reminder or a documentation link. But if it is in the JavaScript code that you are getting errors, kindly share the errors. If you the above solved the problem, accept the answer as the solution.